# Use alias from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to use aliases from a subquery.

```
Fruit table:
name:    is_bio:    from_id:   to_id:
Apple    yes        Spain      Italy

Country table:
id:      packaging_type:    packaging_quantity:
Italy    wood box           12
Spain    paper box          18
```

And I tried something like this:

```
with subquery as (SELECT a.packaging_type, a.packaging_quantity, b.packaging_type, b.packaging_quantity 
FROM fruit
    inner join country a on a.country.id = fruit.from_id
    inner join country b on b.country.id = fruit.to_id
WHERE fruit.name = 'Apple')
SELECT a.packaging_quantity from subquery;
```

But I got an error:

```
ORA-00904: "A"."PACKAGING_QUANTITY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 14
```

Comment: MySQL, if that's really the database that you are using, does not support common table expressions.

Comment: Sorry I want to click to sql but I clicked mysql instead of that and I forgot to delete it.

Comment: remove a. from select query and re run --SELECT packaging_quantity from subquery;--- check whether this works.

Comment: Your CTE does not have a column `A.PACKAGING_QUANTITY` only a column named `PACKAGING_QUANTITY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Your CTE has four columns, but only two column aliases, `packaging_type` and `packaging_quantity`.  The table alias is not the full qualified column name (that is, including the alias or table name), but only the column name itself.

You need to give them distinct names using `as`, such as:

```
with subquery as (
      select a.packaging_type as packaging_type_a,
             a.packaging_quantity as packaging_quantity_a, 
             b.packaging_type as packaging_type_b,
             b.packaging_quantity as packaging_quantity_b
      from fruit inner join
           country a
           on a.country.id = fruit.from_id inner join
           country b
           on b.country.id = fruit.to_id
      where fruit.name = 'Apple'
     )
select packaging_quantity_a
from subquery;
```

Comment: @tmsblgh . . . You should ask a *new* question.  Changing a question after it has been answered is rude, because it can encourage downvotes on the original answers.

Comment: Didn't know that, sorry!